# Start Python CLI app on startup

Tags: boot, cron

I have a Raspberry Pi 3b+ that is booting to the pi user terminal, no GUI. I need to have a small CLI app run after the pi has finished booting.

So far I have tried editing `/etc/rc.local`, and using the `@reboot` in crontab.

Are these the best/correct ways to start an app that needs to be interacted with after bootup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people like to use `/etc/rc.local` or `@reboot` from cron so I will not say it is not the best choice. But I will give you some infos that you have to take attention by using this.

Since version *Jessie* Raspbian replaces classic *SysV* init for booting with *systemd*. To be compatible it emulates *SysV* and `/etc/rc.local` is part of *SysV*. Look at [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). You will find there:

> Some SysV systems support an "rc.local" script that is supposed to be called "last" during boot. In systemd, the script is supported, but the semantics are less strict, as there is simply no concept of "last service", as the boot process is event- and request-based, parallelized and compositive. In general, it's a good idea to write proper unit files with properly defined dependncies, and avoid making use of rc.local.

For the same reason the starting conditions with `@reboot` in crontab can change. `man 5 crontab` says:

> Please note that startup, as far as @reboot is concerned, is the time when the cron(8) daemon startup.  In particular, it may  be  before  some  system  daemons, or other facilities, were startup.  This is due to the boot order sequence of the machine.

A boot order sequence isn't defined with *systemd*.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with a name ending in .service in `/etc/systemd/system` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Write a short description
[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStart=/path/to/program
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now execute `systemctl daemon-reload` so that systemd picks up your new service, and `systemctl enable myservice` (replacing "myservice" with the name of your .service file) to enable it.
Your program will run as the pi user on reboot.

If your program requires network connectivity to function, then add `After=network.target` to the `[Unit]` section.