# How to make a program run on boot in the RPi kernel

Tags: kernel

I'm currently working on a fork on the raspi kernel for streaming cable channels (I have that ready. That's not what I need help with). What I need to know is how to get a program to run on boot (This is a non-built kernel. Just a Github repos @ www.github.com/zurgeg/linux).
So when I boot I want a program that says `hello world!` (in python) run on boot.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: What's a "non-built kernel"? Do you have a running kernel or not?

Comment: No. It's a kernel I'm working on on GitHub @ www.github.com/zurgeg/linux

Comment: Can you replace the `init` command with your program? Although, not sure if this would work with a python script, rather you might need to set `init="/path/to/python /path/to/my/script.py"`. See [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/44950/93934) for an example?

Comment: @RogerJones `init` will never run without a running kernel.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  Programs do not run in the kernel.  Why is what you want any different from running an application as early as possible after boot?

Comment: This program is actually going to look at the data found on a stick that gets cable channel.

Comment: Several programs play video.  They run in user land and talk to hardware via kernel calls.  How is that different to what you plan to do?  These video players are standard Linux user land applications.

Comment: I *think* that "kernel" is irrelevant here. If you wish to start a program *at boot*, this might be what you're looking for: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88291/start-python-cli-app-on-startup/88311#88311

Comment: I’m just trying to make a fork of the rpi os. From what I know it’s the kernel

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Agreed, but the impression I get from question is that they have their own kernel built and running and are asking how to launch an userland program from it.

Comment: @RogerJones If there is a running kernel, why not boot the normal way and run the python script from an autorun script or a cron job?